# overriding matplotlib's panning tool (wx)

Tags: matplotlib, wxpython, toolbar

I'm using matplotlib housed in a wxPython panel to do some heavy duty plotting.  My issues comes when using native panning tool - it's appears as though matplotlib tries to constantly redraw the canvas as you drag the pan handle around.  With the amount of data I'm plotting this is getting really choppy (already optimized with Collections for data etc)

In terms of performance I think it would be much preferable for the canvas to just draw once when the mouse is released at the end of a pan.  I realise this will mean I have to extend the WxAgg NavigationToolbar2 class with my own, but I'm wondering if anyone has attempted something similar to this and can advise me on which functions to override?

many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've spent a lot of time making modification on the matplotlib backends, I've never done this specific change, but I can show you one line of code to comment out that will stop the dynamic updating:

I presume you are using the `WxAgg` backend, if this is the case, open this file: `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_wx.py`

And comment out the line indicated here:

```
def dynamic_update(self):
    d = self._idle
    self._idle = False
    if d:
        #self.canvas.draw() #<--- Comment out to stop the redrawing during the Pan/Zoom
        self._idle = True
```

I tested this and it seems to nicely solve your issue. I did some quick digging and I didn't see any other functions calling this procedure so you might even be able to just change it to:

```
def dynamic_update(self):
    pass
```

...Which is the same code you'll find in the base `NavigationToolbar2` class

(And of course, if you're happy with this change you can do a little more work to make your own custom backend with this kind of modification. Just to make sure you don't lose the change when upgrading matplotlib)

Comment: I knew it would be something simple! Thanks so much that worked a treat - only other thing I would change to that is having the panner 'grab hold' of the canvas at the start, so as you pan around the plot isn't dynamically updating, but the static canvas image is moving around with your mouse with whitespace appearing at the place that will be drawn once released.  This would give a better feel of where you are in the plot while still maintaining the performance benefits.  I have a feeling this could be done using canvas.copy_from_bbox, I will certainly explore this when I have time

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like an elegant fix. When I was digging around in the backends today, I saw some functions you'd probably end up modifying `press_pan()`, `release_pan()` and `drag_pan()`. There was fair amount of inheritance and delegation going on, but I think eventually all the dirty work goes on in the `axes.py` `drag_pan()` function. Anyway, have fun & good luck!