# Tkinter scale widget not updating in realtime

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to use Tkinter.Scale to produce a slider that changes the data within a matplotlib, however I am having issues in getting the plots to update in realtime without having to regenerate the plot window each time.

If I run my code as so, then it works well, but it creates a new window each time I move the slider which is hard to focus upon visually.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

def update(val):
    plt.close()

    global idx
    idx = np.array(w.get())

    t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)
    a1 = np.sin(idx*np.pi *t1)
    a2 = np.sin((idx/2)*np.pi*t1)
    a3 = np.sin((idx/4)*np.pi*t1)
    a4 = np.sin((idx/8)*np.pi*t1)

    """Plotting of data"""  
    fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(4, sharey = False) # create figure
    plt.tight_layout()
    ax1.plot(t1, a1) 
    ax2.plot(t1, a2) 
    ax3.plot(t1, a3) 
    ax4.plot(t1, a4) 

w = tk.Scale(master, from_=0, to=10, command = update)
w.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

I would like the slider to simply re-plot the data each time, however when I move the commands to create the figure preceding the function, as shown below, it no longer updates the plots when I move the slider,  but only when the slider is closed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk


fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(4, sharey = False) # create figure
plt.tight_layout()

master = tk.Tk()

def update(val):

    ax1.cla() # clears the entire current figure but leaves the window
    ax2.cla()
    ax3.cla()
    ax4.cla()

    global idx
    idx = np.array(w.get())

    t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)
    a1 = np.sin(idx*np.pi *t1)
    a2 = np.sin((idx/2)*np.pi*t1)
    a3 = np.sin((idx/4)*np.pi*t1)
    a4 = np.sin((idx/8)*np.pi*t1)

    """Plotting of data"""  
    ax1.plot(t1, a1) 
    ax2.plot(t1, a2) 
    ax3.plot(t1, a3) 
    ax4.plot(t1, a4) 

w = tk.Scale(master, from_=0, to=10, command = update)
w.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Has anyone got any ideas on how to get the data only, and not the whole window, to update as the slider is moved? Apologies if this has been asked already, but I'm failing to find it if so. I cannot use the matplotlib slider option as in the actual script I am sweeping an string variable extracted from a .txt file, not an integer.

Comment: On my end you code only produces a slider and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of your problem I am assuming you want to have some plots that update with each tick of the slider and you do not want the plot recreated each time. The code you have provided does not even create a plot as you don't do anything with `fig`. That said there are a few changed you need.

First off when creating a plot inside tkinter IMO it is best to use the FugureCanvasTkAgg method in matplotlib. This will allow us to draw everything onto a canvas. We also want to `cla()` each axis instead of `close()` the plot. If you close the plot you will need to rebuild it so the best thing to do is clear the axis each time you update.

Here I would first build the plot with the value of zero from the slider and then let the function update the subplots only. This allows us to keep the plot intact and only change the lines in the subplots so we do not need to recreate the plot each time.

Take a look at the below code.

Update: Added in the toolbar and "TkAgg" per [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) comments.

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg


master = tk.Tk()

def update(val):
    global idx, chart_frame, ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4
    ax1.cla()
    ax2.cla()
    ax3.cla()
    ax4.cla()
    idx = np.array(w.get())
    t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)
    a1 = np.sin(idx*np.pi *t1)
    a2 = np.sin((idx/2)*np.pi*t1)
    a3 = np.sin((idx/4)*np.pi*t1)
    a4 = np.sin((idx/8)*np.pi*t1)
    ax1.plot(t1, a1) 
    ax2.plot(t1, a2) 
    ax3.plot(t1, a3) 
    ax4.plot(t1, a4) 
    canvas.draw()

w = tk.Scale(master, from_=0, to=10, command = update)
w.grid(row=0, column=0)

idx = np.array(w.get())

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(4, sharey = False)
plt.tight_layout()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=1)
toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(master)
toolbar_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, toolbar_frame)
canvas.draw()

master.mainloop()
```

Personally I feel that writing code in a non OOP method is frustrating and harder to manage. I think this would be better written in OOP so here is my example for that.

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg


class MyPlot(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.w = tk.Scale(self, from_=0, to=10, command = self.update)
        self.w.grid(row=0, column=0)

        fig, (self.ax1, self.ax2, self.ax3, self.ax4) = plt.subplots(4, sharey = False)
        plt.tight_layout()

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=1)
        toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        toolbar_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
        NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, toolbar_frame)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def update(self, val):
        self.ax1.cla()
        self.ax2.cla()
        self.ax3.cla()
        self.ax4.cla()
        idx = np.array(self.w.get())
        t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)
        a1 = np.sin(idx*np.pi *t1)
        a2 = np.sin((idx/2)*np.pi*t1)
        a3 = np.sin((idx/4)*np.pi*t1)
        a4 = np.sin((idx/8)*np.pi*t1)
        self.ax1.plot(t1, a1) 
        self.ax2.plot(t1, a2) 
        self.ax3.plot(t1, a3) 
        self.ax4.plot(t1, a4) 
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyPlot()
    app.mainloop()
```

I would use `draw_idle()` as [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) mentioned but I am currently seeing a bug that can cause the plot to not be draw with the correct value.

Take this screenshot for example. After sliding the Bar up fast and releasing my mouse button often the value of the plot is not updated properly. This only seams to happen if I let go of the mouse button while sliding the bar up.

This might be an issue only related to Tkinter or some combination of matplotlib and Tkinter. I imagine it is not drawing the last slider value because Tkinter's mainloop is not idle due to my mouse release as this is an event in Tkinter and maybe is interfering.

[image]

Comment: Use `canvas.draw_idle()` instead of `canvas.draw`. The first code also needs to make sure the `"TkAgg"` backend is used, else it might fail. For complete replication, the navigation tookbar is missing from the code.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks I do have the "TkAgg" in my original code just didn't paste in for some reason. Canvas.Draw() works fine. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Draw_idle does not attempt to redraw the canvas while it's being redrawn already. Meaning that it can be significantly faster and prevent freezing if the slider is moved too quickly

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I just got done testing `draw_idle()` and noticed if you do move the slider 2 fast and let go of it then sometimes the plot is not updated with the correct value. I am not seeing this behavior with `draw()`.

Comment: Works fine for me. Not sure what problem there is. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416336/matplotlib-tkagg-backend-performance) for a better explanation.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I understand your reasoning for using `draw_idle()` I am just seeing a strange behavior with it. Take a look at my updated answer. I have a screen shot showing the problem when using `draw_idle()`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help - as a quick solution, the first answer appears to be working fine. I shall look at implementing the others as a much neater option in time.

Comment: @BobbieJim please be sure to select the check box next to the answer that works best for you to show your problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix for your existing code is to actually show the figure (`fig.show`) and make sure it is redrawn each time the slider is moved (`fig.canvas.draw_idle()`)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk


fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(4, sharey = False) # create figure
plt.tight_layout()

master = tk.Tk()

def update(val):

    ax1.cla() # clears the entire current figure but leaves the window
    ax2.cla()
    ax3.cla()
    ax4.cla()

    global idx
    idx = np.array(w.get())

    t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)
    a1 = np.sin(idx*np.pi *t1)
    a2 = np.sin((idx/2)*np.pi*t1)
    a3 = np.sin((idx/4)*np.pi*t1)
    a4 = np.sin((idx/8)*np.pi*t1)

    """Plotting of data"""  
    ax1.plot(t1, a1) 
    ax2.plot(t1, a2) 
    ax3.plot(t1, a3) 
    ax4.plot(t1, a4)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.show()
w = tk.Scale(master, from_=0, to=10, command = update)
w.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

In case the aim is not necessarily to provide a tk slider, an appropriate solution may be the following, using in inbuilt `Slider`. This has the advantage of being completely platform and backend independent.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, sharey = False) # create figure
plots = [ax.plot([])[0] for ax in axes]

fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.12)

t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)

def update(idx):

    a1 = np.sin(idx*np.pi *t1)
    a2 = np.sin((idx/2)*np.pi*t1)
    a3 = np.sin((idx/4)*np.pi*t1)
    a4 = np.sin((idx/8)*np.pi*t1)

    for plot, a in zip(plots, [a1,a2,a3,a4]):
        plot.set_data(t1, a)
        plot.axes.relim()
        plot.axes.autoscale()

    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

update(5)
slider = Slider(fig.add_axes([.1,.04,.6,.03]), "Label", 0,10,5)
slider.on_changed(update)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That works if you don't want to embed the plot in a Tkinter application. I think it would be better to use `FigureCanvasTkAgg` so the slider, plot and anything else they want to add can all be inside the Tkinter application.

Comment: That's not what the question asks for. I'm sure there are plenty of applications where embedding is just overkill and adding a small tk slider next to the plot is all that's needed.

Comment: I don't know if I would call it overkill. Just cleaner. Its not like it takes a lot of work to make it happen. But like I sad your answer works if they have no need for it to be embedded in the Tkinter application.

Comment: I didn't know about the built in slider. I can probably use that on some of my applications.